# Import data into R - argument is empty

Tags: r, import

I am trying to use a R package called GOSemSim, it requires to import a lot of data into variables with a specific format like this:

```
data1 = c("one", "two", "three")
data2 = c("A", "B", "C")
```

When the list of data that I try to import into a variable is longer than 293 then I get the following error message:

```
argument 293 is empty
```

THere are no error with the "" or comma, I computed it with linux, it does not matter what data it is.

This is really weird basically, I tried on two computers with no luck. I tried to import it as a CSV file but the R package won't allow it.

Anyone knows why you cannot import more than 293 data?

Update:
Here is the code and my data at the same time, it is a one liner in R which has never been a problem for me!

```
OQ = c("GO:0000003", "GO:0000070", "GO:0000077", "GO:0000079", "GO:0000082", "GO:0000086", "GO:0000122", "GO:0000212", "GO:0000226", "GO:0000278", "GO:0000279", "GO:0000280", "GO:0000724", "GO:0000725", "GO:0000819", "GO:0000910", "GO:0001932", "GO:0002118", "GO:0002121", "GO:0002165", "GO:0003002", "GO:0003006", "GO:0006022", "GO:0006030", "GO:0006040", "GO:0006139", "GO:0006259", "GO:0006260", "GO:0006261", "GO:0006267", "GO:0006270", "GO:0006275", "GO:0006277", "GO:0006281", "GO:0006302", "GO:0006304", "GO:0006305", "GO:0006306", "GO:0006310", "GO:0006323", "GO:0006325", "GO:0006342", "GO:0006351", "GO:0006355", "GO:0006357", "GO:0006366", "GO:0006464", "GO:0006468", "GO:0006479", "GO:0006725", "GO:0006807", "GO:0006928", "GO:0006950", "GO:0006974", "GO:0006996", "GO:0007010", "GO:0007017", "GO:0007018", "GO:0007049", "GO:0007051", "GO:0007059", "GO:0007062", "GO:0007067", "GO:0007076", "GO:0007088", "GO:0007093", "GO:0007095", "GO:0007098", "GO:0007126", "GO:0007127", "GO:0007131", "GO:0007140", "GO:0007141", "GO:0007143", "GO:0007154", "GO:0007155", "GO:0007156", "GO:0007259", "GO:0007266", "GO:0007275", "GO:0007276", "GO:0007281", "GO:0007282", "GO:0007292", "GO:0007304", "GO:0007307", "GO:0007346", "GO:0007350", "GO:0007365", "GO:0007367", "GO:0007379", "GO:0007389", "GO:0007399", "GO:0007400", "GO:0007417", "GO:0007420", "GO:0007423", "GO:0007444", "GO:0007472", "GO:0007476", "GO:0007552", "GO:0007560", "GO:0008104", "GO:0008213", "GO:0008283", "GO:0008284", "GO:0008315", "GO:0008356", "GO:0009059", "GO:0009611", "GO:0009653", "GO:0009790", "GO:0009791", "GO:0009880", "GO:0009886", "GO:0009887", "GO:0009888", "GO:0009889", "GO:0009890", "GO:0009892", "GO:0009893", "GO:0009896", "GO:0009968", "GO:0009987", "GO:0010032", "GO:0010033", "GO:0010092", "GO:0010389", "GO:0010468", "GO:0010498", "GO:0010556", "GO:0010558", "GO:0010564", "GO:0010604", "GO:0010605", "GO:0010608", "GO:0010629", "GO:0010648", "GO:0010948", "GO:0014016", "GO:0014017", "GO:0014070", "GO:0016043", "GO:0016055", "GO:0016070", "GO:0016310", "GO:0016319", "GO:0016321", "GO:0016441", "GO:0016458", "GO:0016568", "GO:0016569", "GO:0016570", "GO:0016571", "GO:0016572", "GO:0017145", "GO:0018130", "GO:0019219", "GO:0019222", "GO:0019438", "GO:0019827", "GO:0019953", "GO:0022402", "GO:0022403", "GO:0022404", "GO:0022412", "GO:0022414", "GO:0022610", "GO:0023052", "GO:0023057", "GO:0030111", "GO:0030154", "GO:0030178", "GO:0030182", "GO:0030261", "GO:0030422", "GO:0030703", "GO:0030727", "GO:0031023", "GO:0031047", "GO:0031050", "GO:0031056", "GO:0031060", "GO:0031123", "GO:0031145", "GO:0031175", "GO:0031323", "GO:0031324", "GO:0031325", "GO:0031326", "GO:0031327", "GO:0031331", "GO:0031398", "GO:0031399", "GO:0031401", "GO:0031570", "GO:0031572", "GO:0031935", "GO:0032268", "GO:0032270", "GO:0032501", "GO:0032502", "GO:0032504", "GO:0032507", "GO:0032774", "GO:0032776", "GO:0032886", "GO:0033043", "GO:0033044", "GO:0033260", "GO:0033301", "GO:0033554", "GO:0034622", "GO:0034641", "GO:0034645", "GO:0034654", "GO:0034754", "GO:0034968", "GO:0035023", "GO:0035107", "GO:0035114", "GO:0035120", "GO:0035186", "GO:0035194", "GO:0035195", "GO:0035220", "GO:0035282", "GO:0035295", "GO:0035825", "GO:0036211", "GO:0036388", "GO:0040029", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042221", "GO:0042445", "GO:0043009", "GO:0043066", "GO:0043069", "GO:0043161", "GO:0043170", "GO:0043331", "GO:0043412", "GO:0043414", "GO:0043549", "GO:0043631", "GO:0043933", "GO:0044237", "GO:0044249", "GO:0044260", "GO:0044271", "GO:0044419", "GO:0044700", "GO:0044702", "GO:0044703", "GO:0044707", "GO:0044728", "GO:0044763", "GO:0044767", "GO:0044770", "GO:0044771", "GO:0044772", "GO:0044773", "GO:0044774", "GO:0044786", "GO:0044818", "GO:0044839", "GO:0044843", "GO:0044848", "GO:0045132", "GO:0045165", "GO:0045168", "GO:0045185", "GO:0045448", "GO:0045455", "GO:0045787", "GO:0045814", "GO:0045859", "GO:0045892", "GO:0045931", "GO:0045934", "GO:0046331", "GO:0046425", "GO:0046483", "GO:0046580", "GO:0046605", "GO:0046777", "GO:0048070", "GO:0048134", "GO:0048135", "GO:0048285", "GO:0048311", "GO:0048468", "GO:0048477", "GO:0048513", "GO:0048518", "GO:0048519", "GO:0048522", "GO:0048523", "GO:0048563", "GO:0048569", "GO:0048583", "GO:0048585", "GO:0048609", "GO:0048646", "GO:0048666", "GO:0048699", "GO:0048704", "GO:0048705", "GO:0048706", "GO:0048707", "GO:0048731", "GO:0048736", "GO:0048737", "GO:0048754", "GO:0048856", "GO:0048863", "GO:0048865", "GO:0048867", "GO:0048869", "GO:0050789", "GO:0050793", "GO:0050794", "GO:0050896", "GO:0051052", "GO:0051058", "GO:0051128", "GO:0051171", "GO:0051172", "GO:0051225", "GO:0051235", "GO:0051246", "GO:0051247", "GO:0051252", "GO:0051253", "GO:0051276", "GO:0051297", "GO:0051299", "GO:0051301", "GO:0051302", "GO:0051321", "GO:0051325", "GO:0051329", "GO:0051338", "GO:0051351", "GO:0051443", "GO:0051445", "GO:0051641", "GO:0051646", "GO:0051651", "GO:0051704", "GO:0051716", "GO:0051726", "GO:0051783", "GO:0051785", "GO:0060255", "GO:0060429", "GO:0060548", "GO:0060688", "GO:0060966", "GO:0060968", "GO:0060993", "GO:0061138", "GO:0065003", "GO:0065004", "GO:0065007", "GO:0070192", "GO:0070507", "GO:0070887", "GO:0070918", "GO:0071103", "GO:0071359", "GO:0071822", "GO:0071824", "GO:0071840", "GO:0071897", "GO:0071900", "GO:0072028", "GO:0072078", "GO:0072079", "GO:0072088", "GO:0080090", "GO:0090068", "GO:0090304", "GO:0090306", "GO:0098609", "GO:1901071", "GO:1901360", "GO:1901362", "GO:1901576", "GO:1901987", "GO:1901988", "GO:1901990", "GO:1901991", "GO:1902275", "GO:1902299", "GO:1902589", "GO:1902679", "GO:1902749", "GO:1903046", "GO:1903047", "GO:1903308", "GO:1903322", "GO:2000026", "GO:2000112", "GO:2000113", "GO:2001141")
```

Comment: I don't think your problem is diagnosable from the amount of information you have provided us with thus far. What is the file you're importing (let's see an example), what is the code you're using to import it?

Comment: I did it, I am not even importing a file, just the data raw into the variable!

Comment: Once I remove `{SOME MORE DATA}`, I am able to generate the QQ variable. Make sure your problem is reproducible.

Comment: Yes sorry I was maybe not clear and I did not want to spam everything with a huge list but I just pasted my huge list anyway !!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message in itself is informative. If one tries to make it reproducible, it's best to work with small subsets. It usually helps to have a dead stare at your data before trying to reproduce the behavior. For example,

```
OQ = c("GO:0000003", "GO:2001141", )
```

Notice that there are two elements of this character vector. Or are they?

```
Error in c("GO:0000003", "GO:2001141", ) : argument 3 is empty
```

Number 3 is the key. R is expecting three elements. Notice the comma after the second element. Once you remove it, you'll be able to create the `QQ` variable. Scan your real example. I'm sure there's a `, ,` somewhere.

*EDIT*

I tried copy/pasting your code into a script in Rstudio and it produced the error you describe. If you scroll right, you'll notice that syntax coloring is not working at around position 5000. I have folded the code so that it fits on screen and it runs fine.

This is how I folded the vector and it worked.

```
OQ = c("GO:0000003", "GO:0000070", "GO:0000077", "GO:0000079", "GO:0000082", "GO:0000086", "GO:0000122",
       "GO:0000212", "GO:0000226", "GO:0000278", "GO:0000279", "GO:0000280", "GO:0000724", "GO:0000725", 
       "GO:0000819", "GO:0000910", "GO:0001932", "GO:0002118", "GO:0002121", "GO:0002165", "GO:0003002", 
       "GO:0003006", "GO:0006022", "GO:0006030", "GO:0006040", "GO:0006139", "GO:0006259", "GO:0006260", 
       "GO:0006261", "GO:0006267", "GO:0006270", "GO:0006275", "GO:0006277", "GO:0006281", "GO:0006302", 
       "GO:0006304", "GO:0006305", "GO:0006306", "GO:0006310", "GO:0006323", "GO:0006325", "GO:0006342", 
       "GO:0006351", "GO:0006355", "GO:0006357", "GO:0006366", "GO:0006464", "GO:0006468", "GO:0006479", 
       "GO:0006725", "GO:0006807", "GO:0006928", "GO:0006950", "GO:0006974", "GO:0006996", "GO:0007010", 
       "GO:0007017", "GO:0007018", "GO:0007049", "GO:0007051", "GO:0007059", "GO:0007062", "GO:0007067", 
       "GO:0007076", "GO:0007088", "GO:0007093", "GO:0007095", "GO:0007098", "GO:0007126", "GO:0007127", 
       "GO:0007131", "GO:0007140", "GO:0007141", "GO:0007143", "GO:0007154", "GO:0007155", "GO:0007156", 
       "GO:0007259", "GO:0007266", "GO:0007275", "GO:0007276", "GO:0007281", "GO:0007282", "GO:0007292", 
       "GO:0007304", "GO:0007307", "GO:0007346", "GO:0007350", "GO:0007365", "GO:0007367", "GO:0007379", 
       "GO:0007389", "GO:0007399", "GO:0007400", "GO:0007417", "GO:0007420", "GO:0007423", "GO:0007444", 
       "GO:0007472", "GO:0007476", "GO:0007552", "GO:0007560", "GO:0008104", "GO:0008213", "GO:0008283", 
       "GO:0008284", "GO:0008315", "GO:0008356", "GO:0009059", "GO:0009611", "GO:0009653", "GO:0009790", 
       "GO:0009791", "GO:0009880", "GO:0009886", "GO:0009887", "GO:0009888", "GO:0009889", "GO:0009890", 
       "GO:0009892", "GO:0009893", "GO:0009896", "GO:0009968", "GO:0009987", "GO:0010032", "GO:0010033", 
       "GO:0010092", "GO:0010389", "GO:0010468", "GO:0010498", "GO:0010556", "GO:0010558", "GO:0010564", 
       "GO:0010604", "GO:0010605", "GO:0010608", "GO:0010629", "GO:0010648", "GO:0010948", "GO:0014016", 
       "GO:0014017", "GO:0014070", "GO:0016043", "GO:0016055", "GO:0016070", "GO:0016310", "GO:0016319", 
       "GO:0016321", "GO:0016441", "GO:0016458", "GO:0016568", "GO:0016569", "GO:0016570", "GO:0016571", 
       "GO:0016572", "GO:0017145", "GO:0018130", "GO:0019219", "GO:0019222", "GO:0019438", "GO:0019827", 
       "GO:0019953", "GO:0022402", "GO:0022403", "GO:0022404", "GO:0022412", "GO:0022414", "GO:0022610", 
       "GO:0023052", "GO:0023057", "GO:0030111", "GO:0030154", "GO:0030178", "GO:0030182", "GO:0030261", 
       "GO:0030422", "GO:0030703", "GO:0030727", "GO:0031023", "GO:0031047", "GO:0031050", "GO:0031056", 
       "GO:0031060", "GO:0031123", "GO:0031145", "GO:0031175", "GO:0031323", "GO:0031324", "GO:0031325", 
       "GO:0031326", "GO:0031327", "GO:0031331", "GO:0031398", "GO:0031399", "GO:0031401", "GO:0031570", 
       "GO:0031572", "GO:0031935", "GO:0032268", "GO:0032270", "GO:0032501", "GO:0032502", "GO:0032504", 
       "GO:0032507", "GO:0032774", "GO:0032776", "GO:0032886", "GO:0033043", "GO:0033044", "GO:0033260", 
       "GO:0033301", "GO:0033554", "GO:0034622", "GO:0034641", "GO:0034645", "GO:0034654", "GO:0034754", 
       "GO:0034968", "GO:0035023", "GO:0035107", "GO:0035114", "GO:0035120", "GO:0035186", "GO:0035194", 
       "GO:0035195", "GO:0035220", "GO:0035282", "GO:0035295", "GO:0035825", "GO:0036211", "GO:0036388", 
       "GO:0040029", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042221", "GO:0042445", "GO:0043009", "GO:0043066", "GO:0043069", 
       "GO:0043161", "GO:0043170", "GO:0043331", "GO:0043412", "GO:0043414", "GO:0043549", "GO:0043631", 
       "GO:0043933", "GO:0044237", "GO:0044249", "GO:0044260", "GO:0044271", "GO:0044419", "GO:0044700", 
       "GO:0044702", "GO:0044703", "GO:0044707", "GO:0044728", "GO:0044763", "GO:0044767", "GO:0044770", 
       "GO:0044771", "GO:0044772", "GO:0044773", "GO:0044774", "GO:0044786", "GO:0044818", "GO:0044839", 
       "GO:0044843", "GO:0044848", "GO:0045132", "GO:0045165", "GO:0045168", "GO:0045185", "GO:0045448", 
       "GO:0045455", "GO:0045787", "GO:0045814", "GO:0045859", "GO:0045892", "GO:0045931", "GO:0045934", 
       "GO:0046331", "GO:0046425", "GO:0046483", "GO:0046580", "GO:0046605", "GO:0046777", "GO:0048070", 
       "GO:0048134", "GO:0048135", "GO:0048285", "GO:0048311", "GO:0048468", "GO:0048477", "GO:0048513", 
       "GO:0048518", "GO:0048519", "GO:0048522", "GO:0048523", "GO:0048563", "GO:0048569", "GO:0048583", 
       "GO:0048585", "GO:0048609", "GO:0048646", "GO:0048666", "GO:0048699", "GO:0048704", "GO:0048705", 
       "GO:0048706", "GO:0048707", "GO:0048731", "GO:0048736", "GO:0048737", "GO:0048754", "GO:0048856", 
       "GO:0048863", "GO:0048865", "GO:0048867", "GO:0048869", "GO:0050789", "GO:0050793", "GO:0050794", 
       "GO:0050896", "GO:0051052", "GO:0051058", "GO:0051128", "GO:0051171", "GO:0051172", "GO:0051225", 
       "GO:0051235", "GO:0051246", "GO:0051247", "GO:0051252", "GO:0051253", "GO:0051276", "GO:0051297", 
       "GO:0051299", "GO:0051301", "GO:0051302", "GO:0051321", "GO:0051325", "GO:0051329", "GO:0051338", 
       "GO:0051351", "GO:0051443", "GO:0051445", "GO:0051641", "GO:0051646", "GO:0051651", "GO:0051704", 
       "GO:0051716", "GO:0051726", "GO:0051783", "GO:0051785", "GO:0060255", "GO:0060429", "GO:0060548", 
       "GO:0060688", "GO:0060966", "GO:0060968", "GO:0060993", "GO:0061138", "GO:0065003", "GO:0065004", 
       "GO:0065007", "GO:0070192", "GO:0070507", "GO:0070887", "GO:0070918", "GO:0071103", "GO:0071359", 
       "GO:0071822", "GO:0071824", "GO:0071840", "GO:0071897", "GO:0071900", "GO:0072028", "GO:0072078", 
       "GO:0072079", "GO:0072088", "GO:0080090", "GO:0090068", "GO:0090304", "GO:0090306", "GO:0098609", 
       "GO:1901071", "GO:1901360", "GO:1901362", "GO:1901576", "GO:1901987", "GO:1901988", "GO:1901990", 
       "GO:1901991", "GO:1902275", "GO:1902299", "GO:1902589", "GO:1902679", "GO:1902749", "GO:1903046", 
       "GO:1903047", "GO:1903308", "GO:1903322", "GO:2000026", "GO:2000112", "GO:2000113", "GO:2001141")
```

Comment: I understand but I am pretty sure there are no extra commas anywhere, first I checked (both manually and automatically by replacing comma by newline and found no issue), second I made this data list with linux and it would not omit one comma anywhere, this is just weird!

Comment: @user3188922, the line of code you gave doesn't throw any error on my computer

Comment: Really @CathG? But does it import the entire data list into the variable OQ?

Comment: @user3188922, it gives me a 406 items vector (the 293th beeing "GO:0048477"). I'm not using RStudio

Comment: Ok then maybe smtg is wrong my R, but I tried on two computers here! Crap!! I don't know how I am going to  fix that, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear you made it work! Sorry but can you explain what fold code means and how to do it? Never done that before! And why did it not work? just because the entire dataset/code is not visible on R studio?

Comment: @user3188922 It means not all is in one line. Use Enter after every  7th (or so) element.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is a great tip, I had no idea!